# Vue3/Nuxt3: instance in plugin always empty object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3, vue-directives

I want to create a directive which enables me to save component references of a certain type into an array. The functionality is quite easy:

- on mounted: add element to a given array
- on unmounted: remove the exact same element from the array

Link to the playground:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mmhfcj

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('formRef', {
    mounted(el, binding) {
      console.log(binding.instance);
      binding.value.push(el);
    },
    unmounted(el, binding) {
      const foundIndex = binding.value.findIndex(
        (item: any) => item.name === el.name
      );
      if (foundIndex !== -1) {
        (binding.value as Array<any>).splice(foundIndex, 1);
      }
    },
  });
});
```

The usage of the directive:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <AccessMe name="bruh" v-formRef="elements" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const elements = ref([]);
</script>
```

the AccessMe component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ props.name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps<{
  name: string;
}>();

function getName() {
  return 'my name is' + name;
}
defineExpose({ getName });
</script>
```

Why is the instance always an empty object and not the component itself with the prop name and the defined function?